# Submitting value depending on what button is clicked

Tags: html, css

Sorry I'm not sure how to phrase this properly

Is it possible to do this?:

Example I want to have 4 buttons/divs for the user to click on

Maybe with a form like this?

input value="Yes" name="response"

input value="No" name="response"

input value="Maybe" name="response"

input value="Later" name="response"

If the user clicks "Yes" then it will form submit that data with "Yes" to be stored in the database slot of "response"

So it's like 4 boxes with "Yes" "No" "Maybe" and "Later" which can be click by the user after which will be submitted like a form

Sorry once again as I'm lost as to how to do this(hopefully the solution is simple?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hi i have one idea to do this With JQuery

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div>
    <input class="btn1" type="button" value="Yes" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <input class="btn1" type="button" value="No"/>
  </div>

  <div>
   <input class="btn1" type="button" value="Maybe"/>
  </div>

  <div>
   <input class="btn1" type="button" value="Later"/>
  </div>

  <div id="display">
  </div>
   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btn1').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=$(this).val();
 });
 });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pranavadurai/jbxdbkLk/2/

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways you could approach this. A form can have multiple submit buttons, via `<input type='submit' name='custom_name' ...`. You could also have a drop down (`<select>`) that the user selects from the options you present them, and have a separate submit button.

### Examples

#### Multiple Submit Buttons

```
<form id="my_form" ...>
    <!-- actual form contents -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit_value" value="Yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_value" value="No" />
    ...
</form>
```

In this situation, the `POST`/`GET` data for `submit_value` would be set to whatever the user clicked.

#### Dropdown

```
<form id="my_form" ...>
    <!-- actual form contents -->

    <!-- drop down -->
    <select name="my_option">
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
        ...
    </select>

    <!-- normal submit button -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

In this case, the `POST`/`GET` data for this form would be `my_option` for the choice you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

i will propose a solution evolving jQuery, HTML and some database

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hi folk</title>
  <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
          //Here goes your database query
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
          //Here goes your database query
        });

        $("#btn3").click(function(){
           //Here goes your database query
        });

        $("#btn4").click(function(){
          //Here goes your database query
        });

     });
  </script>
</head>

<div>
  <div>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Yes" />
  </div>

  <div>
     <input id="btn2" type="button" value="No"/>
  </div>

  <div>
     <input id="btn3" type="button" value="Maybe"/>
  </div>

  <div>
     <input id="btn4" type="button" value="Later"/>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```